# Fire method after completion of another method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript methods, lets say, function loadDataToTable() and function sortDataInTable(). The first method is exposed by some internal mechanism, so I cannot edit it but I wrote the second one. So, I would like to call the second method as soon as the first method is completed. How do I do this ?

Comment: Think you should add a bit of code. Have you any way to know the first method has finished?

Comment: Is the first method async? Otherwise just execute them one after the other. Unless you are not the one calling loadDataToTable()

Comment: I am calling loadDataToTable myself, I dont have anything regarding this methods except the name. I think its a async call.

Comment: If you have no way to provide a callback to `loadDataToTable()`, then you are out of luck. The only way out is to use `setTimeout()` with a manually tuned timeout... Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information that you have provided, it's not too complicated. Just call both functions one after the other:

```
var response = loadDataToTable();
if(response == "desiredResponse"){
    sortDataInTable();
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: this works only if loadDataToTable() returns something. Thanks for the help though.